# JavaScript/React - access bound 'this' in new Promise constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In my React app, I am trying to call `this.setState()` within the body of a new Promise - however, `this` is `undefined` in the body of the Promise.

The function is in a module called `ui.js`:

```
export const toggleButtonsDisabled = function(buttonsAreDisabled) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        this.setState({"buttonsDisabled": !buttonsAreDisabled}, () => {
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

And it is referenced in a component like so:

```
import { toggleButtonsDisabled } from "../../scripts/ui"

class Test extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.toggleButtonsDisabled = toggleButtonsDisabled.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            "buttonsDisabled": false
        }
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        this.toggleButtonsDisabled(this.state.buttonsDisabled)
            .then(function() {
                // DO SOME STUFF...
            })
    }

    // FORM, ETC...
}
```

If `handleSubmit()` is called, an error comes back saying `cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` - the reference to `this` is lost in the scope of the Promise.

If I rewrite the function as:

```
export const toggleButtonsDisabled = function(buttonsAreDisabled) {
    const reactComponent = this

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        reactComponent.setState({"buttonsDisabled": !buttonsAreDisabled}, () => {
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

then it works, no problem... but is there a more elegant way to handle this? Or am I asking for the impossible?

Comment: Try arrow syntax: `return new Promise(resolve => {`.

Comment: @Andy Thanks! That does it - if you'd make that an answer, I'd accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the interesting qualities of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is that they do not have their own `this` so they look at the local lexical environment for one.

You can solve your issue of having to assign `this` to a new variable by using an arrow function:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.setState({"buttonsDisabled": !buttonsAreDisabled}, () => {
    resolve();
  });
});
```